# Docker Centos 7 image running Apache2 "DocumentRoot ... is not readable"

Tags: apache, docker, centos, selinux

I have a docker container running a Centos 7 image. All it needs to do is run a simple Apache2 server. When the container starts it exits immediately with:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 119 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
DocumentRoot '/var/www/html' is not a directory, or is not readable
```

I did some basic checks:

- Folder exists
- Permissions are ```rwx r_x r_x root root```` for each folder /var/www/html
- Tried `chown -R apache /var/www` (no straw shall remain unclutched!)
- SELinux is disabled (... or is it?)

When I enter the container with a bash entry point, I can then start apache as root with `/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND` and everything works as expected.

So I think its almost certainly a permissions thing. Googling found many pages with my error e.g. 
[Apache restart causes DocumentRoot must be a directory, even though it is a directory and there seem to be no privilege issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786881/apache-restart-causes-documentroot-must-be-a-directory-even-though-it-is-a-dire)
This particular page closely describes what I am getting and the solution in almost every page is configure SELinux. However SELinux is disabled. Even in that link there is comment from the OP

> My version of linux isn't Security Enhanced Linux, so without understanding I tried it anyway: no effect.

Yet they accepted the solution which was configure SELinux.

I think I am missing something, almost certainly SELinux related, but I can't figure it out. The docker image has the following (distinct lack of) SELinux settings:

- /etc/selinux contains only semanage.conf and tmp/ (empty)
- /usr/sbin contains no se* executables
- `rpm -qa | grep selinux`

  - `libselinux-2.5-12.el7.x86_64`
- /etc/sysconfig/selinux does not exist

  - So in the Dockerfile I tried `RUN echo "SELINUX=disabled" > /etc/sysconfig/selinux`
- doing `yum install -y policycoreutils` installs sestatus in /usr/sbin. Running sestatus gives

  - `SELinux status:                 disabled`
  - With or without /etc/sysconfig/selinux

It really looks like SELinux is disabled, yet the error looks so much like it is enabled.

Comment: What Docker image are you running?  If it's a custom image, can you share your Dockerfile?  Can you also include the `docker run` command you're using to start the image?

Comment: Thank you! You have pushed me in the correct direction. I use docker-compose to launch a number of related services. I am moving these services from our ubuntu base to the customer's centos base, but I had not updated the volumes mappings in docker-compose.yml. Changing them from deb to centos paths has solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in this case was due to the way the container was launched.

I use docker-compose to launch this particular container but the paths for the volume mapping were incorrect.

I am still not sure why this causes apache to fail to start in the way it does but correcting the paths fixed the issue.