# DocumentRoot is not a directory, or is not readable

Tags: apache

I'm trying to Install Apache PHP MySQL phpMyAdmin on Windows 10, so I started with Apache so I downloaded it and I installed it as a service with :

```
>httpd.exe -k install
```

and then I typed `httpd.exe -k start`

and this problem shows up

[image]

when I open httpd.config file and change it from :

[image]

to :

[image]

and run `httpd.exe -k start` the error's not there anymore but when I head up to my browser and type `http://localhost` 
I'm supposed to get a page saying : **it works**

but instead I got this :
[image]

I read this

[Apache restart causes DocumentRoot must be a directory, even though it is a directory and there seem to be no privilege issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786881/apache-restart-causes-documentroot-must-be-a-directory-even-though-it-is-a-dire)
https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=1053

but it didn't help. How can I fix this error?

Comment: You have to give Apache permissions on the directory you specified in DocumentRoot.  Look at the next line `<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">`, it does not match the directory you put in your config.  And, please, never put images of code or config. here, it is text, paste it as text.

Comment: Hum another thing it could be, your browser does not connect.  Look at the `Listen` directive to know which port Apache listens to.  You might have to connect to `http://localhost:PORT/`.  Also the Windows firewall by default will block that traffic.  Turn it off to test, then add specific rule to allow it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use /
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache24"
not this
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache24"